# Javascript: split unclosed tags in string?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I have a simple markup language that supports statements like:

```
<pause> <state:OK> <fast> Oh <pause> sure, yep! <pause> Yep I certainly do
```

I want to split these statements into an array like

```
 ["<pause> ", "<state:OK> ", "<fast>", "Oh ", "<pause>",  "sure, yep! ", "<pause>", " Yep I certainly do!"]
```

I'm trying to use a regex like

```
line.split(/(?=<.+>)/)
```

but the array I'm getting is

```
["<pause> ", "<state:OK> ", "<fast> Oh ", "<pause> sure, yep! ", "<pause> Yep I certainly do!"]
```

What regex should I use on the first string, to obtain the results I desire?

Note that I am not parsing HTML.

Comment: How do you possibly end up with `"<state:yea_ok> "`?

Comment: Right. Typo fixed.

Comment: `/(<[\w:]+>)\s*/` and .filter() for the "" matches?

Comment: Try something like `s.split(/(<[^>]+>)/).filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `match` instead of `split`:

```js
var line = "<pause> <state:OK> <fast> Oh <pause> sure, yep! <pause> Yep I certainly do";

var arr = line.match(/<.+?>|\S[^<]*?(?=\s*(<|$))/g)

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You're a wizard, harry

Comment: Small quip: you missed including the spaces after the markup.  Although I don't know why the OP wanted them anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I intentionally kept them out as you can see: seems more useful. NB: OP was not consistent as more often the space was not included.

Answer (score 0):

We can split it by the tags(tokens) and then trim the resulting strings to remove any whitespace. The filter removes falsy values including empty strings.

```
str.split(/(<.+?>)/).filter(_ => (_.trim()));
```

```js
console.log(
"<pause> <state:OK> <fast> Oh <pause> sure, yep! <pause> Yep I certainly do".split(/(<.+?>)/).filter(_ => (_.trim())) 
);
```

Comment: @PHPglue how do you figure?

Answer (score 0):

The fun of regexes: a thousand ways to skin a cat.

```js
const str = '<pause> <state:OK> <fast> Oh <pause> sure, yep! <pause> Yep I certainly do';

const regex = /((?:<[^>]+>\s|\b[^<>]+))/g;

const matches = str.match(regex);

console.log({matches});
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course, the real question is why are you dealing with such ridiculous data. Forego that, you may want to try this:

```js
var testStr = '<pause> <state:OK> <fast> Oh <pause> sure, yep! <pause> Yep I certainly do';
function weirdSplit(str){
  return str.match(/<[^>]+>|[^ ]+[^<>]+(?=\s|$)/g);
}
console.log(weirdSplit(testStr));
```